# Autolayout in code ? height issue?

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

I have Two View say view1 and view2.
- view2 should be at 2 pixel distance from view1 (vertically) and
- Height of view2 should be such that bottom of view2 must be same as bottom of viewcontroller.

How to specify the constraint for this in code ?

Comment: Can you post an image of what your are trying to do?

Comment: I am using NSLayoutConstriaint Class not visual format language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know what you already have in your view hierarchy I've set up a simple example. Look into this bit of code. It creates two new UIViews and position them using constraints.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [UIView new];
    UIView *view2 = [UIView new];

    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[view1(200)]-(2)-[view2]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view1]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view2]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];

}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Code is not that hard to understand. `+ constraintsWithVisualFormat:` method creates an array of `NSLayoutConstraint`s that you add to the superview of your custom views. Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) for more on visual format language. It's very effective at simple layout and saves a bunch of time compared to creating constraints one by one.

If you reeeaaally want to create constraints using `constraintWithItem:` method, here's your code:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:100]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:2]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:200]];
```

It results in the same constraints, but takes up twice the space and is harder to read.So I strongly recommend you to use visual format instead. You should only use `constraintWithItem:` for more complicated layout which visual format can't always handle.

Comment: Thanks Bro. can you write the code using NSLayout class ?

Comment: @aashish what's NSLayout class? Did you mean NSLayoutConstraint? I did use it, look into code.

Comment: [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:2]];

Comment: I want to do with the help of constraintWithItem method.

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:3]];

Comment: @aashish not sure why you want to use this method with such a straightforward layout. See updated answer for the code. If you don't want to use visual format because you are not familiar with it I strongly recommend you to start learning how to use it, it's very efficient.

Comment: @aashish do you understand that `constraintWithItem:` creates the same exact objects of class NSLayout constraint as `constraintsWithVisualFormat:`? The latter just creates a bunch of them in one line, that's the only difference. The mechanism is the same. So visual format method is usually preferred and is much easier to implement and read.